# program for defanging an IP address

Tags: c

Searching for program for defanging an IP address(only with strings)
EX:
Input : 12.34.57.34
Output : 12[.]34[.]57[.]34

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[20],IP[3];
    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
    int s=strlen(a),i;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=='.')
        {
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            printf("[.]);
        }
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
I've got close
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: Whats the error? This code shouldn't compile. `printf("[.]);` has an unmatched double quote. You can see it in the syntax highlighting on the code section.

Comment: `int s=strlen(a)` is superfluous. Simply `for(i=0; a[i]; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(a[i]=='.')
        {
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            printf("[.]);
        }
```

You replaced the dot with the number immediately after it, which I don't think is intended behavior:

123.123 becomes 1231123, so you'll be printing out 123[.]1123

Make it so that when you detect a dot, you just print out "[.]", and then go on to the next character (so basically just print "[.]" and do nothing). No need to replace the character, or print it out afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it gives 1[.].1.[.].1[.].1 as output. Still need to edit out '.' from the output.

Comment: Again, you are doing it wrong. When you detect a dot, do not print it out. Just print out "[.]".   `if(a[i] == '.') printf("[.]"); else printf("%c", a[i]);`     What is confusing here?